# Date.parse works on string but not variable of the same string?

Tags: javascript

a little confused here. I've got a date.parse that's working for a string, but not for a variable that has the exact same string in it.

```
finish2 = Date.parse('2016-01-29 16:15:28'),
finish = Date.parse(div.data('completed')),
```

And

```
console.log(finish2);
console.log(finish);
```

And the output is:

```
1454083140000
NaN
```

The div.data is coming from:

```
data-completed="{{ $construction->completed_at }}
```

Which is equal to 2016-01-29 16:15:28 (the same format as the one that's working). So I'm confused.. The string is pulling in the same string as I have done manually.. A little lost.

Any help would be appreciated!

HTML output:

```
<div class="well well-sm tm" data-completed="2016-01-29 16:15:28">
```

Comment: There must be something different about it than what you think. What does `console.log(div.data('completed'))` output?

Comment: it works for me .. var div={"data":"2016-01-29 16:15:28"}; Date.parse(div.data);

Comment: maybe data-completed is not returning what you think it is returning.

Comment: @JohnnyHK If I do that I get "undefined". So confused!

Comment: Are you sure this is true: `'2016-01-29 16:15:28' === div.data('completed')`

Comment: In your example code, should the first `Date.parse()` be `Date.parse('2016-01-29T16:15:28')` instead?

Comment: I get "undefined" if I just console.log the div.data('completed') but in the HTML it's coming through as:

<div class="well well-sm tm" data-completed="2016-01-29 16:15:28">

Comment: not a valid date string ... won't work in all browsers

Comment: @charlietfl I'm confused about the fact that a string I enter manually that's exactly the same format as the div.data. Shouldn't they both fail if that's the case?

Comment: It's likely `undefined` as it's not set yet at the time you're calling `div.data('completed')`. Looks like you might be mixing jQuery and Angular here which can be messy.

Comment: The fact that "console.log(div.data('completed'))" is giving you 'undefined' is exactly why you're getting the Parse error.  As JohnnyHK said, you might be running into a kind of race condition here, if you're mixing frameworks. Why are you putting the date into this custom attribute? Wouldn't it be easier to just populate a hidden field, or put this as text inside a non-rendering element? If you are using JQuery, what do you get for `console.log($(div).prop('data-completed'));`?

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but I don't believe `div.data('completed')` should return anything unless `div` is a jQuery object.  If it is simply a reference to an element, you would want to do `$(div).data('completed')`